# Pull a Date from a comment

Tags: sql-server

Good Morning All.

I have a comment field from an invoice system. The user goes into the invoice and leaves a comment/note on it. The source system tags each note with a date. However, the month is either a single digit or a double digit based on the date the note was entered same with the day. So the issue I am having is that I want to pull all of the invoice notes that start with a certain time period. So the notes always start like either one of these:

6/7/16 7:51 AM

11/11/16 8:11 PM

Is there a way to pull the date from the beginning of the note say using AM or PM as the starting point and working back to the beginning of the string?

Comment: _"Is there a way to pull the date from the beginning of the note say using AM or PM as the starting point and working back to the beginning of the string"_ Uhm, why the date is a string at all?

Comment: Not a great design here but shouldn't be that hard. Can you provide us some sample data and what you expect for output? Of course if you are storing multiple notes on the same row this is going to get pretty nasty.

Comment: Tim - the date is pre-pended to the actual note it is not a specific date field.

Comment: Sean it IS nasty. Unfortunately I didn't design it, I am just left being expected to report on it...

Answer (score 0):

What I can tell is that you might use `Regular Expressions` to extract the date from the string, but SQL server doesn't support the regular expression!

A work around is to use CLR, here an article that explain how to achieve what you want. [Regular Expressions in MS SQL Server 2005/2008](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42764/Regular-Expressions-in-MS-SQL-Server)

To get some help on how to build the regular expression to match the dates, here another article that might help you : [Regular Expression Library](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=4&categoryId=5&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

The date regular expression could be `((\d{2})|(\d))\/((\d{2})|(\d))\/((\d{2})) ((\d{2})|(\d)):((\d{2})|(\d)) [AP]M`

Hope this will help you